Custom Shortcut to type a string containing spaces. Kubuntu 23.10
I need to to create a new key that types a string that contains one or more spaces.
So for example, if I need frequently enter an address string like "123 Main St."
Using "Custom Shortcuts" I create a new global shortcut with "Send Keyboard Input", then define a new trigger (F8) and and action "1:2:3: :Shift+m:a:i:n: Shit+s:t".   However this returns "123MainSt" without the spaces.  I'm sure I need to either use a "Alt" code or a character value.    Trouble is I can't seem to find documentation or the right thing to use.  Anybody know this off hand?

In the action field enter
1:2:3:Space:Shift+M:a:i:n:Space:Shift+s:t

to get the desired result:
123 Main St



Thank You Mook765!    So obvious I didn't even think of that!
